# Laravel DB select generates unexpected SQL error after some data bindings

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, phpmyadmin

The following SQL that works fine in phpmyadmin console:

```
SELECT  count(tca.cavity_id),GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(tca.cavity_id)),equipments.eqtype_id, eqtypes.title FROM cavity_actions AS tca

  LEFT JOIN equipments ON tca.equipment_id = equipments.id
  LEFT JOIN eqtypes ON equipments.eqtype_id = eqtypes.id
WHERE tca.job_id = 6 AND tca.action_id = 2
AND tca.created_at BETWEEN '2018-01-31 00:00:00' AND '2018-02-01 00:00:00'
AND equipments.eqtype_id = 2
```

This is a screen shot from the phpmyadmin that shows the working query:
[image: Screen shot from phpmyadmin]

However, when I try to use `DB::select()` with data binds like the following:

```
$sql = 'SELECT  count(tca.cavity_id),GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(tca.cavity_id)),equipments.eqtype_id, eqtypes.title FROM cavity_actions AS tca

  LEFT JOIN equipments ON tca.equipment_id = equipments.id
  LEFT JOIN eqtypes ON equipments.eqtype_id = eqtypes.id
WHERE tca.job_id = :jobId AND tca.action_id = 2
AND tca.created_at BETWEEN :start AND :end
AND equipments.eqtype_id = :eqtypeId';
    foreach ($eqtypes as $eqtype){
        DB::enableQueryLog();
        $data = [ 'jobId' => $job->id, 'eqtypeId' => 1,  'start' => $start, 'end' => $end];
        $out[$eqtype->id] = DB::select($sql,$data);
       // dd(DB::getQueryLog());

        return $out;
    }
```

It generate pure SQL error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1140 In aggregated
>   query without GROUP BY, expression #3 of SELECT list contains
>   nonaggregated column 'factory2.equipments.eqtype_id'; this is
>   incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by (SQL: SELECT
>   count(tca.cavity_id),GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(tca.cavity_id)),equipments.eqtype_id,
>   eqtypes.title FROM cavity_actions AS tca
>
> LEFT JOIN equipments ON tca.equipment_id = equipments.id LEFT JOIN
>   eqtypes ON equipments.eqtype_id = eqtypes.id WHERE tca.job_id = :jobId
>   AND tca.action_id = 2 AND tca.created_at BETWEEN :start AND :end AND
>   equipments.eqtype_id = :eqtypeId)

Trying to debug the issue, I tried to give fixed value in the query for each data bindings, and by this way it works.

Additionally and specially for `:eqtypeId` when I remove it works:

```
AND tca.created_at BETWEEN :start AND :end
AND equipments.eqtype_id = 1';
    foreach ($eqtypes as $eqtype){
        DB::enableQueryLog();
        $data = [ 'jobId' => $job->id,  'start' => $start, 'end' => $end];
        $out[$eqtype->id] = DB::select($sql,$data);
       // dd(DB::getQueryLog());
```

but at just using :eqtypeId and supply it to the data binding, it generates that SQL error again!

**What I mean** that everything works fine till I uses data bindings for the last where clause condition `AND equipments.eqtype_id = :eqtypeId` in laravel application.

The only way that allows my code to work in laravel is replacing `...AND equipments.eqtype_id = :eqtypeId` with `AND equipments.eqtype_id = %s` then use `sprintf` like: `$out[$eqtype->id] = DB::select(sprintf($sql,$eqtype->id),$data);`

I need an explanation why it does not work with ordinary data bindings for the last where condition only! What is the difference that data bindings make on the query?

Both phpmyadmin and laravel application are using the same MySQL server and the same PHP version on the Same Apache server!

Comment: Your query is non-sensical, because you are selecting aggregates (i.e. `COUNT` and `GROUP_CONCAT`) along with non aggregate individual columns.  Update your question and tell us what you are trying to select here.  Note that in most databases your query would have failed _everywhere_.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I just edited the question with a screen shot that shows that it works via phpmyadmin.

Comment: My words are falling on deaf ears.  Your query is _invalid_, it _should not_ run anywhere, and you need to fix it.  You _can't_ select aggregate and non aggregate columns at the same time, it makes no sense.

Comment: Doesn't older mysql versions allow that though? I thought it was only recently they started enforcing aggregate/non-aggregate mismatches? Or am I completely off base?

Comment: @btl The used MySQL server is version  5.7.21

Answer (score 0):

This is a result of `strict mode` being on. Laravel has a setting for strict mode in `config/database.php`.

It's generally a good idea to have strict mode as it will tell you when you're doing something ambiguous. But if you don't want it on, you can change the setting.

```
    'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',

        // Changes MySQL strict mode settings
        'strict' => false,

        'engine' => null,
    ],
```

Comment: Note that it is the same query with the same MySQL configurations the only difference between it works or not is just using bindings. In other words, the query works fine in laravel when one of binding data is not used. i.e replacing it in the query directly.